# Working with multi dimensional hashes in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

quick question about pushing to a multi-dimensional hash in Perl.  I have the following variables:

```
%pids #name of hash 
$pid = 24633 #key of the has 
$time 00:0 #time reference 
$line #has a line full of data
```

I am inputing $pid and $time in from $line.  If the key 24633 exists along with reference element 05:3, then it add the line to 05:3 and use 05:3 as a key.

pids{24633}{05:3}

I've tried:

```
if ($pids{$pid}{$time}){
     @{$pids{$pid}{$time}} -> $line;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
if ($pids{$pid}{$time}){
    push @{$pids{$pid}{$time}}, $line;
```

But it's keep giving me a "Not a HASH reference" when it tries to do the push. Any suggestions? Thanks!

This is how I'm building the hash:

```
foreach my $key (keys %pids){
    if ($key =~ $mPID){
    push @messages, $line;
    }
}
```

Here's the hash structure:

```
$VAR1 = {   
      '17934' => [
                   '14:3'
                 ],
      '17955' => [
                   '13:3'
                 ],
      '24633' => [
                   '05:3'
                 ],
      '6771' => [
                  '04:1'
                ],
      '7601' => [
                  '06:0'
                ],
};
```

Comment: You have a hash of arrays, but you try to use it as a hash of hashes. Your code is also not relevant to the question, as it does not show how you build your hash.

Comment: I have included how I built it, thanks

Comment: Nope, you haven't. You've included how you use the hash to try to build an array, which would with the current code fill the array with undefined values. (Because you use `$key`, but store `$line`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%pids` structure is initialized as a hash of arrays when you're trying to access it as a hash of hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %pids = (   
    '17934' => [ '14:3' ],
    '17955' => [ '13:3' ],
    '24633' => [ '05:3' ],
    '6771'  => [ '04:1' ],
    '7601'  => [ '06:0' ],
);

print $pids{7601}[0], "\n";  #  Prints 06:0

print $pids{7601}{"06:0"}; # Error
```

You'll have to figure out why your `%pids` is a hash of arrays first if you really want it to be a hash of hashes of arrays.

- [`perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: why would I use one over the other? forgive me, still learning. And thanks for the link, lots of great info

Comment: Why would one use a hash over an array?  You'd use an array if you wanted an ordered list of values.  You'd use a hash if you wanted key, value pair relationships.  Only you know your data and therefore which one is needed.

Comment: Thank you. I meant a hash of arrays or a hash of hashes